# Commented an xml node through python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have xml file in which looks like this

```
<Configuration>
....
...
  <Toolkit name="Logging">
    <Logger>
     ...
     ...
    </Logger>
  </Toolkit>

</Configuration>
```

I want to transform this into -

```
<Configuration>
....
...
  <!--<Toolkit name="Logging">
    <Logger>
     ...
     ...
    </Logger>
  </Toolkit>-->

</Configuration>
```

through python.

P.s. 1) I tried `re` but failed to do this. Perhaps I don;t know how to use it correctly.
2) There could be multiple `Toolkit` in `xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

```
div_test='<Configuration>\
  <Toolkit name="Logging">\
    <Logger>\
    </Logger>\
  </Toolkit>\
  <Toolkit name="Logging1">\
    <Logger>\
    </Logger>\
  </Toolkit>\
</Configuration>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test, "xml")
el = soup.find('Toolkit',{'name':'Logging'})
el.replace_with(Comment(str(el)))
print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
 <!--<Toolkit name="Logging"> <Logger> </Logger> </Toolkit>-->
 <Toolkit name="Logging1">
  <Logger>
  </Logger>
 </Toolkit>
</Configuration>
```